# Can I save a random generated var so I can call the result back later in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I generate a random var to create random scenes. One of them is location. I want it to be possible to generate a location with one button. Then press another button to generate a new location and when I press on the first button I want to get back the generated location I generated with that button
The function I generate the location with looks like this

```
function inhoudFunction()
            {
                    var locs = ["movie", "park", "garden", "home"];
                    var loc = locs[Math.floor(Math.random()*locs.length)];
                    
                    document.getElementById('inhoud').innerHTML="<h2>Locatie</h2>" + loc;
```

And these are the buttons I use to run the codes

```
<button type="button" onclick="introFunction()">intro</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="midFunction()">mid</button>
```

To know if the button was pressed twice I used this code

```
function introFunction(){

    if (introClicked == 1){
        document.getElementById('introClicked').innerHTML="<div id=inhoud></div>";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('introClicked').innerHTML="<div id=inhoud></div>";
        inhoudFunction();
        introClickedFunction();
    }
```

And  introClicked gets updated with this function

```
var introClicked = 0;

function introClickedFunction(){
    introClicked = introClicked + 1;
}
```

But once I press the button twice I get nothing back

Comment: What is an initial value of the `introClicked` variable? Is the `midFunction` function defined?

Comment: introClicked is 0 and once the button is clicked the value get sets to 1.
midFunction is the same as inhoudFunction for now. But in the future I want it to work the same as introFunction where the variable get stored and is able to be called back

Comment: I see I forgot to add the part of code for introClicked. I added it now in the original problem

Comment: Do you ever call introClickedFunction?

Comment: I run it in the introFunction in the else statement

Answer (score 1):

Save the generated value directly as a custom field of your `<button>` element.

In the example below, the element is passed to the click handler function as `event.target`. The function reads the `gen_locations` field. If it's not set, then it generates the random value and sets it.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _e => {
  const locs = ["movie", "park", "garden", "home"];

  document.getElementById('inhoud-button1').addEventListener('click', inhoudFunction);
  document.getElementById('inhoud-button2').addEventListener('click', inhoudFunction);

  function inhoudFunction(event) {
    let genlocs = event.target.gen_locations;
    if (!genlocs) {
      genlocs = []
      for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        genlocs.push( locs[Math.floor(Math.random() * locs.length)] );
        event.target.gen_locations = genlocs;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById('inhoud').innerHTML = "<h2>Locatie</h2>" + JSON.stringify(genlocs);
  }

});
```

```html
<div id="inhoud"></div>

<button id="inhoud-button1">Inhound 1</button>
<button id="inhoud-button2">Inhound 2</button>
```

I've cleaned the code by avoiding inline javascript event handlers. Those are bad! :)

***Edit: improved to show storing 2 generated randoms at once per button***

Comment: Sometimes, both buttons generate the same value, so if you don't see it changing when you click the second button, run the snippet again!

Comment: Thank you so much. Does this also work with multiple variables? In the end I want to run around 40 variable to generate one table

Comment: You could set your own field (e.g. `gen_location`) as a plain object or an array, therefore containing as many values as you wish

Comment: Just to be clear: I've made it so the value is tied to the button itself, so if you have 40 buttons each generating 1 value, above code will work as is

Comment: The end product will generate 40 different variables and show them in a table. And this has te be done twice with two different buttons

Comment: OK so your `gen_location` will become `gen_locations`, an array containing 40 generated values

Comment: Can you maybe show an example with two variables. I tried it but the second variable gets undefined

Comment: There. Updated the snippet so it now stores an array of 2 values at each generation, and dumps it to `#inhoud` as JSON